# Difference between 余 and 多; the use of 岁 and 年

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

**1.** If I want to say "more than a hundred years", which one is correct?

a. 百余年

b. 一百多年

One of the example in ichacha "五十余年: fifty odd years" makes me wonder why 余 is used instead of 多. So, when should we use 余 and 多?

**2.** In almost every online dictionary I've checked, aside from being classifier for age ('years old'), 岁 can also mean 'year'. Is there any example of it being used to say 'year' but not age?

Comment: users note that 2 comments have been deleted by persons other than author (superuser?) after having been allowed for a substantial length of time to the possible benefit of some users

Comment: @user6065 I thought you've deleted it... I was still digesting the comment TT_TT

Comment: preceding comment greatly appreciated, in particular since it may suggest to those in power at this site to wait somewhat longer before deleting comments they determine to be unfit

Answer (score 2):

Both are fine but there is a subtle difference.

百余年 is rather formal and literary, and sounds like something from transcript of a documentary / speech / piece of writing. You would rarely say 百余年 in daily conversations.

一百多年 can also be used in writing but people also use it in colloquial situations.